# Vue problem :mouseover in v-for at component calls method instantly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem with using `:mouseover` in `v-for` loop in `<component>`.
The method passed into the `:mouseover` is called for each element, but should only for `hovered` elements.

```html
<Single-technology 
                v-for="technology in $t('about.presentation.technologies')"
                :key="technology.name"
                :name="technology.name"
                :percentage="technology.percentage"
                :description="technology.description"
                :mouseover="showInfo()"
            />
```

```js
 methods: {
        showInfo() {
            console.log("info");
        }
    }
```

What do I expect?
I except that the hovered (mouseover) elements call the `showInfo()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If `mouseover` is a prop, the value should be passed as the *method name* (not a call, which would be evaluated immediately):

```html
<!-- BEFORE: -->
<Single-technology :mouseover="showInfo()" />

<!-- AFTER: -->
<Single-technology :mouseover="showInfo" />
```

But if `mouseover` is actually an event name, you're incorrectly using `v-bind` when you should be using `v-on`:

```html
<!-- BEFORE: -->
<Single-technology :mouseover="showInfo()" />

<!-- AFTER: -->
<Single-technology @mouseover="showInfo()" />
```